# Why is an error thrown when adding a tuple to a Map?

Tags: scala, scala-3

I don't understand why this works:

```
val romanNum = immutable.Map(1 -> "I", 2 -> "II", 3 -> "III", 4 -> "IV", 5 -> "V")
val romanNumWith10 = romanNum + (10 -> "X")
```

But this gives an error:

```
val romanNumWith10 = romanNum + (10, "X")
```

Both `(10 -> "X")` and `(10, "X")` return a Tuple2.

So both should work, but `(10, "X")` doesn't.

By the way, this works:
`val romanNumWith10 = romanNum + ((10, "X"))`

My Scala version is 3.1.2

It seems that Scala sees Int and String separately and not as a Tuple2, but why?

Answer (score 4):

Remember that **Scala** does not have operators, only methods and lots of sugar syntax.

```scala
// Thus, this:
val romanNumWith10 = romanNum + (10 -> "X")
// Desugars to:
val romanNumWith10 = romanNum.+(10.->("X"))
// And since `10.->("X")` returns a tuple, then it works.

// Whereas, this:
val romanNumWith10 = romanNum + (10, "X")
// Desugars to:
val romanNumWith10 = romanNum.+(10, "X")
// E.g. trying to call the `+` method with two arguments; which is an error.

// Finally, this:
val romanNumWith10 = romanNum + ((10, "X"))
// Desugars to this:
val romanNumWith10 = romanNum.+((10, "X"))
// Which is again correct.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit suprised, it does not infer the right type not even in Scala 3. This dates back from Scala 2 as well. For example, in Scala 2.13.8:

```
val mymap             = Map(2 -> "w")
val x1: (Int, String) = (1, "x")
```

Doing:

```
  val mymap2 = mymap + x1 // ok
```

compiles, but doing:

```
  val mymap3 = mymap + (1, "x") // type mismatch
```

does not.

FWIW, if a method receives a polymorphic argument, you will be tripped when using a tuple there too:

```
  def iCanConsumeAnything[T](x: T) = println(s"Consumed $x !")
```

Calling it with a tuple, using the same syntax:

```
  iCanConsumeAnything(1, "x") // Consumed (1,x) !
```

compiles ok, as it treats `(1, "x")` as a tuple, and not as 2 arguments. But it would confuse anyone into thinking the method receives 2 arguments.

It's generally a bad practice to call the method like this, as well as adding tuple literals to a `Map` instead of using the special right arrow `->` syntax.